# How to strip the debugging rule of the BOOST library in Windows

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, ida

I'm building software now that uses BOOST library.
I build it on Windows using MSVC2015 and / or MSVC2017
When I open the software in IDA after compiling I have lots of symbols from BOOST in this style:

```
class boost::_bi::bind_t<enum  boost::msm::back::HandledEnum
```

Symbols that IDA can find in its definition:

```
; DATA XREF: sub_40FC60+59↑o
.data:00F74FC0                                         ; reference to RTTI's vftable
```

I compile the code in release mode.
I tried static and dynamic link to boost
I changed msvc Strip Private Symbols to Yes (/PDBSTRIPPED)
I changed msvc Enable Run-Time Type Info to No

What else can I do to strip all the symbols of this kind (of `reference to RTTI's vftable` type) from my binary? (Not necessarily in the context of the `BOOST` library but in general, get rid of them).

Comment: Is _"reference to RTTI's vftable"_ really a "symbol"? Doesn't it just describe a thing? I don't see any connection between this and the Boost type you've given as an example.

Comment: it's described staff with the correct names so yes - it's a symbol, and i use boost just as an example .

Comment: Then why don't you give a consistent example that actually shows what you're asking about?

Comment: i do , i want to remove all rtti symbols , and i gave an example and what i have tried and didn't worked...

Comment: I don't think you quite understand how RTTI works. You can disable RTTI but then your program won't work any more. Either way, unless I'm missing something, these are not "symbols". You have shown no evidence that there are any symbols remaining in the program.

Comment: this string line `class boost::_bi::bind_t<enum  boost::msm::back::HandledEnum` is in the exe , usn't it a proof?

Comment: So the first code block is a verbatim quote as well? That wasn't clear.

Comment: yes, sorry if it's wasn't clear